# Python requests 422 error on post

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape a website like GitHub that requires login authentication, but unlike Github, it does not have and an API. I've followed [these](https://brennan.io/2016/03/02/logging-in-with-requests/) instructions and many others, but nothing seems to work and just returns a 422 error.

```py
from lxml import html

url = "https://github.com/login"
user = "my email"
pas = "associated password"

sess = requests.Session()
r = sess.get(url)

rhtml = html.fromstring(r.text)

#get all hidden input fields and make a dict of them
hidden = rhtml.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden}

#add login creds to the dict
form['login'] = user
form['password'] = pas

#post
res = sess.post(url, data=form)

print(res)
# <Response [422]>
```

I've also tried just `sess.post(url, data={'login':user, 'password':pas})` with the same result. `get`ing the cookies first and using them in the post doesn't seem to work either.

How can i get my login page, preferably without using Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the form `action` is different from the login page.

This is how you can do it using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://github.com/login"
user = "<username>"
pwd = "<password>"

with requests.Session() as s:

    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    hidden = soup.find_all("input", {'type':'hidden'})
    target = "https://github.com" + soup.find("form")['action']
    payload = {x["name"]: x["value"] for x in hidden}

    #add login creds to the dict
    payload['login'] = user
    payload['password'] = pwd

    r = s.post(target, data=payload)
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this finally worked. Turns out i was also using the wrong password, but what i was doing didn't work with the correct one either.